# import csv file in sqlitedb using php script

Tags: php, sqlite, csv, import

hello guys i have a big problem with **sqlite** commands...
currently i m using this script for creating new sqlite database using **attach** commanad...

//Here MyDB is Class That extends SQLite3 class

```
$db = new MyDB($user_db);

$db->exec("ATTACH 'my.db' as mydb");

$result = $db->query("CREATE TABLE COPY AS SELECT * FROM mydb.table");

$db->exec("DETACH DATABASE livebizz");
```

But when i use import command its not work correctly

```
$db->exec("import my.csv tablename");
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys its that my mistake about this question...
**import** command is not working with sqlite objects only following command...

https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html

and after i use with sql file to import data's in sqlite database...